# File access error - already in use when reading from file (vb.NET 2.0)

Tags: .net, file-io

Using:

```
Dim fileStream as System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)
```

as opposed to (see end of line):

```
Dim fileStream as System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

In

```
Dim fileStream as System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)
Dim data(fileStream.length) as Byte
fileStream.read(data, 0, fileStream.length)
fileStream.close()
```

Would the addition of the `FileAccess.Read` flag stop the encountering of *already in use when reading from file* exception?

Put better - Can you access in Read-only mode even when open somewhere else?

Comment: The much bigger deal is FileShare.ReadWrite

Comment: So it looks like when you don't give it a FileAccess flag, its access is read/write by default (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the access explicitly with `FileAccess.[Value]` then the `System.IO.File.Open(...)` function defaults to read/write, inducing the error.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open.aspx